# unnecessary request call for js and css after calling wp_dequeue_script

Tags: functions, themes, theme-customizer

**called unnecessary js and css request**

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/includes/js/scripts.js

**orignal it was**

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js
http://www.serpentcs.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js

this is happen after i written a function in **function.php**

```
// below function is used to deque script on certain page
function wpa_scripts() {
    // if this is not the contact page, remove the script
    if(!is_page('contact-us') ){
        wp_dequeue_script( 'contact-form-7' ); // only available onto contact-form-7
    }
    if(is_page( 'contact-us' ) || is_page('blog-serpent-consulting-service')){
        wp_dequeue_script( 'themepunchtools' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'showbiz-jquery.themepunch.showbizpro.min' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyphoto-js' );      
        wp_dequeue_script( 'owl-js' );              
        wp_dequeue_script( 'revmin' );                      
    }
}
 //adjust priority to make sure this runs after the plugins add their scripts/styles
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );
```

After i remove a function still calling a js and css file.

**after change** `add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );`
to `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_scripts', 100 );`

work's fine all pages but not in "contact-us" page

it's include below link

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/includes/js/scripts.js

i need

http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js
http://www.serpentcs.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js

Comment: Apart from the wrong hook, you should dequeue and deregister to completely remove scripts and styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook to use is `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of `wp_print_scripts`

Comment: i had done changes but in "contact-us" page include link is not perfect it's still add wrong link,as i metion in my question and in other page works fine.